# Is there a way to ignore columns that don't exist on INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a [MySQL GUI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/) to migrate some sites to a new version of a CMS by selecting certain tables and running the `INSERT` statement generated from a backup dump into an empty table (the new schema). There are a few columns in the old tables that don't exist in the new one, so the script stops with an error like this:

> Script line: 1    Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Cherry-picking the desired columns to export, or editing the dump file would be too tedious and time consuming. To work around this I'm creating the unused columns as the errors are generated, importing the data by running the query, then dropping the unused columns when I'm done with that table. I've looked at `INSERT IGNORE`, but this seems to be for ignoring duplicate keys (not what I'm looking for).

Is there any way to preform an `INSERT` while ignoring columns that don't exist in the target table? I'm looking for something "painless", like some existing SQL functionality.

To clarify, I'm working with a bunch of backup files and importing the data to a local database for testing before moving it to the live server. Example of the kind of solution I'm hoping for:

```
-- Don't try to insert data from columns that don't exist in "new_table"
INSERT INTO `new_table` {IGNORE UNKNOWN COLUMNS} (`id`, `col1`, `col2`) VALUES 
  (1, '', ''),
  (2, '', '');
```

If something like this simply doesn't exist, I'm happy to accept that as an answer and continue to use my current workaround.

Comment: If the field list mentions columns that don't exist, it may very well contain columns that accidentally match. For whatever you know, it may be the table name that is wrong, making you accidentally insert invalid data in the wrong table. This is a very bad idea. If the insert it wrong, let it fail.

Comment: There are plenty of queries that are dangerous if used incorrectly or "accidentally", I don't see why this would be any exception.

Comment: Sure, but having non-existent columns in the query suggests a direct error and will fails. INSERT is no exception. A SELECT query fails just as well.

Comment: Look at the last line of my post: I was surprised no one just answered: "No, this doesn't exist" and explained why it's a bad idea, but no one did. That was the answer I was ready to accept but then a +50 bounty came along.

Comment: Well, I did explain why it's a bad idea. Couldn't say if it exists. Not straight forward in the INSERT statement syntax, but there are always tricks, as shown in some of the answers. They can have 50 points for their creative solutions. I'm happy with anyone reading my comment. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current technique seems practical enough. Just one small change.

Rather than waiting for error and then creating columns one by one, you can just export the schema, do a diff and find out all the missing columns in all the tables.

That way it would be less work.

Your gui will be capable of exporting just schema or the following switch on mysqldump will be useful to find out all the missing columns.

```
mysqldump --no-data -uuser -ppassword --database dbname1 > dbdump1.sql
mysqldump --no-data -uuser -ppassword --database dbname2 > dbdump2.sql
```

Diffing the dbdump1.sql and dbdump2.sql will give you all the differences in both the databases.

Comment: Good addition, definitely useful when migrating from one database schema to a different one. +50 for that.

Answer (score 3):

you can write a store function like that:

```
sf_getcolumns(table_name varchar(100))
```

return string contatining the filed list like this:
'field_1,field_2,field_3,...'

then create a store procedure

```
sp_migrite (IN src_db varchar(50), IN target_db varchar(50))
```

that runs trugh the tables and for each table gets the filed lists and then creates a string like

```
cmd = 'insert into ' || <target_db><table_name> '(' || <fileds_list> || ') SELECT' || <fileds_list> || ' FROM ' <src_db><table_name>
```

then execute the string for each table

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not sure what any of this means - but it looks like more trouble than it's worth? I guess I was hoping for a keyword or something I can add to the existing `INSERT` script that would just ignore the unknown columns, since I already have a workaround of my own. I'll see if I can make sense of this and give it a shot, thanks. I'm working with existing backup files, so not too sure this is what I'm after.

Comment: I see this has a vote, so I take it this is not a bad solution (even if my limited sql skill cannot comprehend it yet). Should I assume from this answer that what I'm specifically looking for *does not* actually exist?

Comment: @WesleyMurch - yes.  It's really a **TERRIBLE** idea to have the engine handle field mis-alignment for you.  It indicates you don't know what you are inserting, which is a major problem.

Comment: @JNK: I don't think it indicates he doesn't know what he's inserting. It only indicates the data is in different format than required and the engine doesn't seem to have a native way to remedy that.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any way to preform an INSERT while ignoring columns that don't exist in the target table? I'm looking for something "painless", like some existing SQL functionality.*

No, there is no "painless" way to do so.

Instead, you must explicitly handle those columns which do not exist in the final tables.  For example, you must remove them from the input stream, drop them after the fact, play dirty tricks ([`engine=BLACKHOLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) + triggers to INSERT only what you want to the true target schema), whatever.

Now, this doesn't necessarily need to be *manual* -- there are tools (as [Devart noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704318/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-columns-that-dont-exist-on-insert/7886583#7886583)) and ways to query the db catalog to determine column names.  However, it's not as easy as simply annotating your INSERT statements.

Perhaps the CMS vendor can supply a reasonable migration script?

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer, unfortunately I am the CMS vendor :) I have a migration system for the latest versions but was trying to quickly crank out updates from a much older version.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables and databases are on the same server and you ***know*** that the common columns are compatible, you can easily do this with `GROUP_CONCAT`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, and a prepared statement.

**This example creates two similar tables
and inserts the data from the common columns in
table_a into table_b. Since the two tables have
a common primary key column, it is excluded.** (Note: the database [table_schema] I am using is called 'test')

```
create table if not exists `table_a` (
  `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
  `a` varchar(2) default null,
  `b` varchar(2) default null,
  `c` varchar(2) default null,
  `d` varchar(2) default null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

create table if not exists `table_b` (
  `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
  `a` varchar(2) default null,
  `b` varchar(2) default null,
  `c` varchar(2) default null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

insert into table_a
  (a, b, c, d)
values
  ('a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'),
  ('a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2'),
  ('a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3');

-- This creates a comma delimited list of common
-- columns in table_a and table_b. It also excludes
-- any columns you don't want from table_a

set @common_columns = (
  select
    group_concat(column_name)
  from
    information_schema.columns
  where
    table_schema = 'test'
    and
    table_name = 'table_a'
    and
    column_name not in ('id')
    and
    column_name in (
      select
        column_name
      from
        information_schema.columns
      where
        table_schema = 'test'
        and
        table_name = 'table_b'
    )
);

set @stmt = concat(
  'insert into table_b (', @common_columns, ') ',
  'select ', @common_columns, ' from table_a;'
);

prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

select * from table_b;
```

The prepared statement ends up looking like this:

```
insert into table_b (a, b, c)
select a, b, c from table_a;
```

Don't forget to change the values for `table_name` and `table_schema` to match ***your tables and database (table_schema)***. If it is useful you could create a stored procedure to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

[dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) will give you an opportunity to [compare and synchronize](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) data between two databases.

By default data comparison is performed only for the objects with the same names; you can use automatic mapping or map database objects manually. dbForge Studio allows you to customize mapping of tables and columns, so you can compare data of objects with non-equal names, owners, and structure. You may also map columns with different types, however this may result in data truncation, rounding, and errors during synchronization for certain types.

Answer (score 0):

found your question interesting.

I knew that there was a way to select the column names from a table in MySQL; it's `show columns from tablename`. What I'd forgotten was that all of the MySQL table data is held in a special database, called "information_schema".

This is the logical solution, but it doesn't work:

```
mysql> insert into NEW_TABLE (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='NEW_TABLE') values ...
```

I'll keep looking, though. If it's possible to grab a comma-delimited value from the `select column_name` query, you might be in business.

Edit:

You can use the `select ... from ... into` command to generate a one-line CSV, like the following:

```
mysql> select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='NEW_TABLE' into outfile 'my_file' fields terminated by '' lines terminated by ', '
```

I don't know how to get this to output to the MySQL CLI stdout, though.

Answer (score 0):

I carefully read all these posts because I have the same challenge. Please review my solution:

I did it in c# but you can do it any language.

Check the insert statement for columnnames. If any is missing from your actual table ADD them as a TEXT column coz TEXT can eat anything.

When finished inserting into that table, remove the added columns.

Done.