# Postgres - drop data for column that doesn't exist on INSERT

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have an unreliable data feed that is being directly pushed into a postgres database.

The feed mostly includes a given set of column names but in rare instances may include columns that were not previously defined, which means in those rare instances the insert to postgres breaks.

I'm looking for a solution to insert the columns from the feed while dropping any columns caused by undefined column names.

One obvious easy solution is to maintain a list of acceptable columns and drop any rouge columns before inserting. And this would work but I'm hoping to avoid it since the feed has very tight timeout parameters and the more I modify the data before pushing to a database the more I risk a timeout. Currently there is a very simple python snippet that builds the insert commands with data as is without any parsing:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});'.format(
    my_table_name,
    ", ".join(columns),
    ", ".join(data)
))
```

My question is is there a way to do this on the fly on the postgres side? Aka drop data for columns not previously defined while inserting the rest on the fly?

I saw a similar ish problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704318/is-there-a-way-to-ignore-columns-that-dont-exist-on-insert) but the solution doesn't seem to work for postgres as far as I can tell.
If no such solution exists that's still useful information to know and I can fall back to pre-parsing the data where possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are using psycopg2 I would use its sql module to build the queries: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html. The following is assuming the data is being provided as a list of dicts.Then I would use the sql.Placeholder for the parameters. Include only the columns you want in the column list.  Then the query will ignore those items that do not have a column that matches the parameter names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using psycopg2 you could do the following: Fetch the table columns before inserting and filter unwanted columns out:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql 
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor


def fetchTableColumns(cur, table):
    sql = """
        select
            attname::varchar as "column",
            pg_type.typname::varchar as "type",
            pg_type.typcategory as "category",
            NULL as "parent",
            attnotnull as "null"
        FROM
            pg_attribute, pg_class, pg_type
        WHERE
            attrelid = pg_class.oid
            AND pg_attribute.attisdropped = False
            AND relname = %s
            AND attnum > 0
            AND atttypid = pg_type.oid
    """

    cur.execute(sql, (table, ))
    columns = [col['column'] for col in cur.fetchall()]
    print('Columns for table: %s are %s' % (table, columns))
    return columns


def insert(cur):
    table_name = 'accounts'
    values = {
        'username': 'foobar',
        'email': 'foobar@gmail.com',
        'pwd': 'bar4000#',
        'birth': '01/01/2010',
        'country': 'France',
        'gender': 'm'
    }

    columns = fetchTableColumns(cur, table_name)
    filteredValues = {k: v for (k,v) in values.items() if k in columns}  # just keep the values that are named by the columns of the table.

    query = sql.SQL("insert into {} ({}) values ({})").format(
        sql.Identifier(table_name),
        sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, filteredValues.keys())),
        sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(filteredValues.keys())))

    print (cur.mogrify(query, list(filteredValues.values())).decode('utf-8'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    repo_dbausername = 'mf_usr'
    repo_dbapassword = 'XYZ'
    repo_host = 'localhost'
    repo_port = '5959'

    con = psycopg2.connect(user=repo_dbausername,
          password=repo_dbapassword,
          host=repo_host,
          port=repo_port,
          database="mf")
    cur = con.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    insert(cur)
```

Output:

```
Columns for table: accounts are ['id', 'username', 'pwd', 'user_id', 'plid', 'email', 'last_login', 'ctime', 'parent', 'token', 'atime', 'stime', 'status']
insert into "accounts" ("username", "email", "pwd") values ('foobar', 'foobar@gmail.com', 'bar4000#')
# as you can see birth, country, gender do not appear in the query.
```

**Note**: For the sake of speed/performance you could implement a cache for the columns returned by `fetchTableColumns` and refresh the cache periodically.
In case you need it faster you could write a stored procedure does the same, but directly in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it might help to show example. Modified from psycopg2 docs:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html

```
columns = ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4"]
q2 = sql.SQL("insert into {} ({}) values ({})").format(
     sql.Identifier("some_table"), 
     sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
     sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Placeholder, columns)))
print(q2.as_string(conn))
insert into "some_table" ("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4") values (%(col_1)s, %(col_2)s, %(col_3)s, %(col_4)s)
data_dict = {"col_1": 1, "col_2": 2, "col_3": 3, "col_4": 4, "col_a": "a", "col_5": 5}
```

When query is run "col_a" and "col_5" will be ignored as there is no placeholder for them.

Comment: This still falls into a less desirable solution of having to parse and catch the bad columns on the script side not on the database side. But it does take me closer to what I need so thumbs up for that!

Comment: I'm not following, all you need to keep track of is the columns in the table and use those for the INSERT. With the code above any columns not matching will be ignored.